# Split pane into two halves using Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, jtabbedpane

Can anyone suggest me how can I divide my `JTabbedPane` in two equal  horizontal sections? My Pane has three tabs in it. I want to divide the second tab pane (tab 2) into two equal halves?

### Code for Tabbed Pane

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class Monitor{
  public static void main(String[] args){
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("WELCOME");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();
  frame.add(tab, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  JButton button = new JButton("1");
  tab.add("tab1", button);
  button = new JButton("2");
  tab.add("tab2", button);
  button = new JButton("3");
  tab.add("tab3", button);
  frame.setSize(400,400);
  frame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a single row `GridLayout` for the `JPanel` that is placed in that tab.  With two components in it, they will each have half the space.  E.G.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Monitor {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("WELCOME");
                // A better close operation..
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();
                frame.add(tab, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                JButton button = new JButton("1");
                tab.add("tab1", button);

                // this GridLayout will create a single row of components,
                // with equal space for each component
                JPanel tab2Panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0));
                button = new JButton("2");
                tab2Panel.add(button);
                tab2Panel.add(new JButton("long name to stretch frame"));
                // add the panel containing two buttons to the tab
                tab.add("tab2", tab2Panel);

                button = new JButton("3");
                tab.add("tab3", button);
                // a better sizing method..
                //frame.setSize(400,400);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code snippet examples for my above code that can help?

Comment: @Dojo_user Take a look at [How to Use GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for examples

Comment: Thanks Andrew!! This is working but I wanted to divide the windows horizontally, this one is dividing it vertically.  Which parameter I need to change to divide the windows horizontally in the same code.

Comment: I think it should be JPanel tab2Panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1)); for horizontal option..

Comment: If you check the [JavaDocs for the `GridLayout` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout-int-int-) you'd probably be able to see  that `new GridLayout(1,0)` would be `new GridLayout(0,1)` ;)

Comment: BTW - when making a `JTabbedPane`, I always get mixed up with the meaning of the horizontal or vertical split.  Is it the component orientation or the divider orientation..?  So I just try it and if wrong, change it.  ;)